# docker-compose up not running app correctly

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, docker-compose

I'm very new to docker. I have a mean stack app that and have configured the dockerfile for frontend and backend as you can see below. When I run `docker-compose up` it appears to finish, but when I go to localhost I'm greeted with this instead of my mean stack app.

[image]

I'm not really sure why, but appreciate any help with this.

backend Dockerfile

```
FROM node

MAINTAINER Phil

WORKDIR /src

COPY . /src

RUN npm install

RUN npm install -g nodemon

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

frontend Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
MAINTAINER Phil


VOLUME /Users/Phil/Documents/myapp/myapp-docker/frontend/dist:usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: ./frontend
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        links:
        - node
        volumes:
        - "/Users/Phil/Documents/myapp/myapp-docker/frontend/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html"
    node:
        build: ./backend
        ports:
        - "3000:3000"
```

console output:

```
Building node
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping myapp-docker_web_1 ... done

C:\Users\Phil\Documents\myapp\myapp-docker>docker-compose up --build
Building node
Step 1/8 : FROM node
 ---> 2f1ff44a8bb5
Step 2/8 : MAINTAINER Phil
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 78d7fb0bb77a
Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 70e753257f23
Step 4/8 : COPY . /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2903a77a03ef
Step 5/8 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 582d4f3b0a7b
Step 6/8 : RUN npm install -g nodemon
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1c9d67ce2743
Step 7/8 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0d77a648b020
Step 8/8 : CMD ["npm", "start"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9adfbe7156f2
Successfully built 9adfbe7156f2
Successfully tagged myapp-docker_node:latest
Building web
Step 1/4 : FROM nginx
 ---> 2073e0bcb60e
Step 2/4 : MAINTAINER Phil
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1fba608ad1fa
Step 3/4 : VOLUME /Users/Phil/Documents/myapp/myapp-docker/frontend/dist:usr/share/nginx/html
 ---> Running in 122358e91315
Removing intermediate container 122358e91315
 ---> 2a54fcb0a4e6
Step 4/4 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in 95117506887d
Removing intermediate container 95117506887d
 ---> 36a7c7bac5b8
Successfully built 36a7c7bac5b8
Successfully tagged myapp-docker_web:latest
Recreating myapp-docker_node_1 ... done
Recreating myapp-docker_web_1  ... done
Attaching to myapp-docker_node_1, myapp-docker_web_1
node_1  |
node_1  | > backend@1.0.0 start /src
node_1  | > node ./package.json
node_1  |
myapp-docker_node_1 exited with code 0
web_1   | 2020/02/06 20:09:02 [error] 6#6: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1",
host: "localhost"
web_1   | 172.18.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2020:20:09:02 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping myapp-docker_web_1    ... done
```

backend package.json

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node ./package.json"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.612.0",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.8",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "create-hash": "^1.2.0",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.11",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-s3": "^2.9.0"
  }
}
```

Here's my directory layout in case that's relevant

[image]

Comment: can you show your frontend dist/-folder?

Comment: I wonder if it's related to another sub directory I have to navigate through since it's dist/my-app/[files] https://postimg.cc/MntD9mFM  If so where would I make that change?

Comment: i was thinking the same , but in my testcases even if all files are in subfolder the original nginx index.html had been removed.

Comment: "The WORKDIR command is used to define the working directory of a Docker container at any given time. The command is specified in the Dockerfile. Any RUN , CMD , ADD , COPY , or ENTRYPOINT command will be executed in the specified working directory." --> You are using /src both for the WORKDIR and COPY. Would you like to copy WORKDIR files to /src/src? If not, ```COPY . .``` will do.

Comment: using  ```COPY . .``` gives me 403 forbidden instead of getting the nginx splashscreen. Any ideas why?

Comment: This is the message I get when using ```COPY . .``` and try to launch localhost: https://postimg.cc/3WHf8TqY

Comment: @Wasbeer While redundant, his COPY works correctly because he uses absolute path (/src). What you are saying would be true if he wrote: COPY . ./src. So your suggestion makes sense to keep code clean, but the explanation is not quite correct.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't actually need the Dockerfile for frontend. You would definitely have to remove the VOLUME declaration but I suggest removing the whole file and using the "image: nginx" directly in your docker-compose.yml.

Since you are not building your frontend application, you need to make sure you have index.html in frontend/dist before runnning `docker-compose up`.

Also your backend applications fails to start because it looks like it tries to run `node ./package.json`. Check the definition of your `start` task in `package.json`.

After making these changes you can try and rerun your docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
        - "/Users/Phil/Documents/myapp/myapp-docker/frontend/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html"
    node:
        build: ./backend
        ports:
        - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: dist folder does have index.html in it. I replaced my docker-compose file with yours, tried changing package.json start field to ```node server.js``` or ```nodemon server.js``` , but haven't been able to get it to pass the build. ```nodemon server.js``` gave me this error https://postimg.cc/5jZtNVY9. I'm not really sure what I should put under start to get it working. Also I added my package.json file above to my original question.

Comment: If your nodejs app is broken, I think that is a problem for a different thread. If you want to validate that my answer works, then create a file index.html in your `dist` folder and run `docker-compose up`. You will see the page instead of the nginx homepage. Normally the dist folder is populated as part of building your application.

Comment: I think the directories aren't getting copied correctly. 
I got passed the bcrypt error by adding npm uninstall bcrypt and then npm install bcrypt in dockerFile so that's no longer an issue, but It doesn't seem to find my check-auth file inside middleware from the src folder postimg.cc/fVQpbHf0. Cannot find module '../backend/middleware/check-auth path wouldn't be correct if I'm working from src folder

Answer (score 0):

You're pointing at the wrong folder.
Your index.html is in /dist/my-app, like i saw from the photo you posted here:
https://postimg.cc/MntD9mFM.

Modify your Dockerfile and docker-compose to point to the correct folder.

## Build 1

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
MAINTAINER Phil
#optional
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

VOLUME /Users/Phil/Documents/myapp/myapp-docker/frontend/dist/my-app:usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: ./frontend
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        links:
        - node
        volumes:
        - "/Users/Phil/Documents/myapp/myapp-docker/frontend/dist/my-app:/usr/share/nginx/html"
    node:
        build: ./backend
        ports:
        - "3000:3000"
```

## Build 2 (better)

You can also ignore Dockerfile cause docker-compose point already to your volume so your new docker-compose will look like:

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        links:
        - node
        volumes:
        - "/Users/Phil/Documents/myapp/myapp-docker/frontend/dist/my-app:/usr/share/nginx/html"
    node:
        build: ./backend
        ports:
        - "3000:3000"
```